# Cannot extract the executable file from zip archieve in Mac

Tags: java, macos, unzip

I want to extract Unix executable file from zip archieve. It works properly  on Windows but does not work on Mac. My code downloads the zip file and extracts it into specific location. It does extract the file but the file is executable file and it extracts it as a TextEdit Document. When I extract it by manual, I get the executable file.Should I force something or is there any permission ? Thanks in advance.

Here is my decompress function :

```
    public void decompress(String zipFilePath, String extractedFilePath) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(extractedFilePath.toString()));
        ZipEntry ze = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
        while (ze != null) {
            String filename = ze.getName();
            File newFile = new File(zipFilePath +_config.configProperties().getPathSeparator()+ filename + _config.configProperties().getVersion());

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int len;
            while ((len = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fos.close();
            ze = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipInputStream.closeEntry();
        zipInputStream.close();
    }catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which kind of executable? What about the extension?

Comment: The kind that I want is Unix Executable, as I said I can get it by manual extracting, but code gives me document.

Comment: Can you post the size differences of the different versions?  Also the output of `xxd manual.bin | head` and `xxd codeverion.bin | head`

Comment: There is no size differences. But I could not follow the second thing. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: As long as you don't set the executable flag `x` for your created file it will be handled as _normal_ file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I found the solution.

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod u+x " + filepath);
```

When I put this in my code block it worked.As I guessed earlier it needs this permission. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Mac doesn't know what to do with a `.exe` file by default unless you have a Windows virtual machine on your system (in which case an `.exe` file will be opened by the virtual machine when double clicked on).  The file might be perfectly extracted with your code (which is likely) but if it has an `.exe` extention or no extention at all then it will just default to a TextEdit document since Mac doesn't know what else to do with it.

You can verify the SHA1 checksums of the file before and after compression to make sure they are identical.

`your-mac:demo$ shasum manual_extraction.bin`

`your-mac:demo$ shasum code_extracted_version.bin`

It would interesting to see the results of the following commands on your Mac from the terminal for both the manually extracted version (the one that is perfect) and the version your code extracts (the one that is corrupted):

`your-mac:demo$ xxd manual_extraction.bin| head`

`your-mac:demo$ xxd code_extracted_version.bin| head`

And just a side note - I noticed that you have `extractedFilePath` parameter being passed in as a `String` but still call `extractedFilePath.toString()` later in the `ZipInputStream()`.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I forgot to say, the file type is Unix Executable.

Comment: updated my answer with the commands to get the output of (from `xxd` and `shasum`)

Comment: Ah.  Well we were about to get to the permission issue because both `shasum` and `xxd` would have verified that the files are identical (therefore your code was working as expected).  Glad it's working for you now.